# How to use bold font combined with plain font and line breaks in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, line-breaks, subtitle

In a plot made with the `ggplot2` package I want to put a subtitle with a part of the text in bold and the other in plain fonts. Also, I would like to make 2 lines of text.

So far I've been trying with the `expression()` and `bold()` functions, and the `\n`; but I can't get the expected result:

> **Item 1:** Text
>
> **Item 2:** Text

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mpg,
       aes(x = cyl,
           y = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(subtitle = expression(bold("Item 1:")*" Text\n"*bold("Item 2:")*" Text"))
```

[image]

Comment: I like to use the `ggtext` package, as it gives so many options, including those that you mention. https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @p0bs in his comment one option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of the `ggtext` package which allows to style text via markdown and/or HTML/CSS, e.g. to switch to `bold` fontface wrap text inside `**`, to add a line break use the HTML tag `<br>`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = cyl, y = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(subtitle = "**Item 1:** Text<br>**Item 2:** Text") +
  theme(plot.subtitle = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]